# Symfony2 annotation @Cache not working

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on a Symfony2 project. I want to add a cache to my classes and methods. Trying to achieve this through Annotations like so:

```
/**
 * @Cache(expires="+5 minutes", public=true)
 */
class MyCacheClass
{
public function MyCacheMethod()
{
/...../
}
}
```

I include this library:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Cache;
```

I followed this [Symfony2 Documentation page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/cache.html). But this does not seem to work at all. Am I doing something wrong?

```
HTTP Response Header:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
    Cache-Control:public
    Connection:Keep-Alive
    Content-Type:application/json
    Date:Tue, 13 Jan 2015 11:59:53 GMT
    Expires:Tue, 13 Jan 2015 12:04:54 GMT
    Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
    Server:Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) PHP/5.5.16 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 OpenSSL/1.0.1h
    Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

Comment: How are you testing the cache headers? And is the cache definitely turned on in the configuration?

Comment: I go to app/cache/annotations and the folder is empty and I know there should be a a file fore each cached method.

Comment: And your [annotations are turned on](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html) in autoload? (Bear in mind it can be less obvious that annotations aren't working than other things, because of course until everything's working properly, they're just comments...)

Comment: Yes it is. It is wired why it deoes not work I have done this sometime ago before and it worked the same way I am trying to work it out here but here it does not work...]

Comment: plus i am using anotations for @Route do declear services for injections so ye 100% anotations should work

Comment: Could you humour me and directly double-check the actual cache headers that you're configuring, rather than looking for those files you mentioned?

Comment: Sorry but I do not fully understand your question

Comment: The annotation in your question specifies that Symfony should send HTTP cacheing headers. I'd like you to test if those headers are actually being sent, by looking at what comes back in the headers of a response when you request whatever you've configured to send them. (Bear in mind that if you want Symfony itself to cache responses based on those headers, you'll need to [make sure you add an actual cache of some kind](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html))

Comment: Please have a look at my Edits

Comment: Well, there you go: the annotations are doing exactly what you've told them to: `@Cache(expires="+5 minutes", public=true)`. You've got a `Expires:Tue, 13 Jan 2015 12:04:54 GMT`, which is five minutes into the future, and you've got `Cache-Control:public`. As far as I can see your annotations are producing the perfect result. You may want to edit your question further to explain what you expect to be seeing, if that isn't it.

Comment: You can also define cached by number of seconds: @Cache(public=true,maxage="300")

Comment: hmmm OK well how cines then the cahce isynt showing iunder this dir ... app/cache/annotations ?